# how to make file Object with relation path in spring project

Tags: java, spring, file, path

```
@RequestMapping("/goCollectionTestPage/")
    public ModelAndView goCollectionTestPage(@RequestParam(value="xmlPath", 
    defaultValue="/xml/Collection/Armani Prive/FW 2007 Haute Couture.xml") String xmlPath)
{
list = xmlParser.getXmlData(xmlPath);
}
```

> this is controller

```
public List<String>getXmlData(String xmlFilePath) throws Exception {
File xmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
```

> and this is xml parser class

but it make the exception like

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xml\Collection\Armani Prive\FW 2007
>   Haute Couture.xml (Could not find the path specified)

when i tried change default value /xml/collection... to xml/collection 
it found file as C:\WINDOWS\System32\xml\Collection\ ....

my .xml file path is at

> /TFProject/src/main/webapp/xml/Collection/Armani Prive/FW 2018 Haute
>   Couture.xml (projectpath)

i need help

how can i make a file Object with relation path in spring?

Comment: Have u tried using classpath? `classpath:main/webapp/xml/Collection/Armani Prive/FW 2018 Haute Couture.xml `
(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards)

Comment: thanks for answer! but i tried another way that is use request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+inputPath; that convert project path to absolutepath and i solved it :)